# Can you construct an ActiveRecord scope with a variable query string?

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Setup:

- I'm using Ruby on Rails with ActiveRecord and MySQL.
- I have a `Coupon` model.
- It has an attribute called `query`, it is a string which could be run with a `where`.

For example:

```
@coupon.query
=> "'http://localhost:3003/hats' = :url OR 'http://localhost:3003/shoes' = :url"`
```

If I were to run this query it would either pass or fail based on the `:url` value I pass in.

```
# passes
Coupon.where(@coupon.query, url: 'http://localhost:3003/hats')
Coupon.where(@coupon.query, url: 'http://localhost:3003/shoes')
# fails
Coupon.where(@coupon.query, url: 'http://localhost:3003/some_other_url')
```

This query varies between `Coupon` models, but it will always be compared to the current url.

**I need a way to say: Given an ActiveRecord collection `@coupons` only keep coupons with queries that pass.**

**The structure of the `where` is always the same, but the query changes.**

Is there any way to do this without a loop? I could potentially have a lot of coupons and I am hoping to do this an ActiveRecord scope. Something like this?

`@coupons.where(self.query, url: @url)`

Perhaps I need to write a user defined function in my database?

Using multiple variables in a query is easy, but where the thing you are comparing your variable to is also a variable - that has me stumped. Any suggestions very appreciated.

Comment: The concept of storing a query in a model attribute is quite unusual. It looks as if all the urls are routes within the Rails app itself, is that right? What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: @LesNightingill Yes I understand it's a bit unusual, but no matter how I restructure things I keep coming back to this problem in one form or another - that's why I decided to post on here for the first time in a decade lol.

Comment: Continuing since I hit character limit @LesNightingill

I can't elaborate in too much detail because this is for work I'm afraid. But essentially I have a model with various queries stored in it that run some logic comparing a current value to various stored values. 

Given a value X in my controller that I get on any given request, instances of my coupon model have logic stored as a SQL query string. One coupon (coupon1) might say "X = A OR X = B" and a different coupon2 might say "NOT X=A".  In this case, if X is equal to A then coupon1 would pass and coupon2 would fail.

Comment: I need a way to run these queries, preferably in a Coupon scope to restrict which ones are returned based on the value of X (say current url). I am trying to do this without a loop for performance reasons. Though conceptually I could say "go through each coupon, pull out the query value and the id, run each one and return the ids of the coupons that pass."

Comment: Kinda feel like this could be accomplished with something like a user defined function in my sql db that says 'pull out the value from the `coupon.query` column and run it with the given variable, but I don't have a lot of experience with user defined functions.

Comment: Sorry to ramble. It's such a weird problem, I'm trying my best to describe it. Any input is certainly appreciated.

Comment: the concept of storing queries in the database suggests (to me at least) an ill-conceived design decision earlier in the project. And now you are running into the shortcomings of that decision. The good news is that software is soft and you now have the opportunity to rectify that decision and make everybody's life easier going forwards. Of course, at work, we may run into resistance, but perpetuating poor design does not benefit the company.

Answer (score 0):

I would agree with Les Nightingill's comment that this looks like something that should probably be solved at a more architectural level. I'd imagine an easy refactoring to extract a new `CouponQuery` model that's a 1:n table containing multiple entries for a `coupon_id` for each query `url` that should pass. Then you could use a simple join like

```rb
Coupon.joins(:coupon_query).where(coupon_queries: { url: my_url })
```

If adding a new table is not an option, and if you're running on a newer MySQL version (>= 5.7), you could consider transforming the `query` column (or adding a new `json_query` column) into a MySQL JSON field and using the [new `JSON_CONTAINS` query](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html).

If from the user-side they should be able to manage the queries as a plain text field, you could use a `before_save` hook on your model to translate this into the separate table structure or JSON format respectively.

But if neither is an option for you and you really need to stick with the `query` column that stores a plain string, then you could use a `LIKE` query to match the sub-string `'your-url' = :url`:

```
Coupon.where('url LIKE "%? = :url%"', my_url)
```

which, if you e.g. pass 'http://localhost:3003/hats' as `my_url` would return something like this SQL query:

```
SELECT `coupons`.* FROM `coupons`
WHERE (url LIKE "%'http://localhost:3003/hats' = :url%")
```

Comment: So, adding a table is an option. But the tricky thing is that I'm not just looking for matches amongst several URLs. Instances of my model each have different rules using complex logic for comparisons, and in the future they will use other variables besides the current url.

For example one coupon could have a rule such as "Show if URL is X or Y". And another could have a different structure that says "Show if URL is NOT Z". Some have groups of rules with parenthesis like "(X AND Y) OR Z". It all uses WHERE query structure. But they are potentially quite different.

Comment: Ooh okay, now I see what you mean. That makes it of course quite a bit more tricky... Is the condition always only looking at the URL and is it always a full URL or could there also be different parameters in there or partial matches?

Comment: For right now it is just a url. There will be other parameters in the future to compare against, but that can all be accomplished with `where` query logic. If I can plug a variable (url) into a stored where query then the world is my oyster. Using a second parameter or a chain of AND/OR logic would not be much increase in complexity since it would still be just one query. And I have a different model responsible for constructing the queries safe from injection. 

I'm reading about stored procedures which let you to run dynamic SQL and I think that might be the direction I have to go in.

Comment: By the way, thanks for taking the time to analyze my question and discuss with me @Nicolas. Really appreciate your time!